# Delete tag "aquaemacs"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

Please delete [aquaemacs](/questions/tagged/aquaemacs), and put the only question in it under [aquamacs](/questions/tagged/aquamacs), because there is no "aquaemacs".

Comment: No more questions with that tag now

Comment: There isn't the need to open a question on the meta site, for a tag used from just a question. You could have edited the question yourself.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: He doesn't have retag privileges on SO.

Comment: @TheEstablishment He just needs to edit the question, and remove the tag. If the tag is used from just a question, it will be automatically removed, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replaced the tag on the question, took about 1.07 seconds ;)

If it keeps coming back, it might be worth making it a synonym, but not really worth it for just one question.